# Django Help: Resolving NOT NULL constraint failed error with CreateView

Tags: python, django, create-view

I am new to stackoverflow, python and Django, have a question on the '(NOT NULL constraint failed: sixerrapp_gig.user_id)' error I am getting when i click submit on the form.

Pretty sure it is because I have not assigned a user_id value from what I have found on StackOverflow thus far, but I am not sure how to do it using the django CreateView.

The project exercise is based on a clone of fiverr.com.

Please see code below:

in models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils import timezone
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse #for model forms

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    avatar = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    about = models.CharField(max_length=1000)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

class Gig(models.Model):
    CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
        ("GD", "Graphics & Design"),
        ("DM", "Digital & Marketing"),
        ("VA", "Video & Animation"),
        ("MA", "Music & Audio"),
        ("PT", "Programming & Tech")
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    category = models.CharField(max_length = 2, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=6)
    photo = models.FileField(upload_to='gigs')
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    create_time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('my_gigs')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.views import generic
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from .models import Gig
from .forms import GigForm

class CreateGig(CreateView):
    model = Gig    
    fields = ['title','category','description','price','photo','status']
```

gig_form.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}

{% block page %}

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
{% include 'sixerrapp/form-template.html' %}
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

What i think i need is for the user field to get a value automatically when the form is submitted. Not sure what I am missing in my code to do that.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to handle that in `form_valid()` method of the view.

```
class CreateGig(CreateView):
    model = Gig    
    fields = ['title','category','description','price','photo','status']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super(CreateGig, self).form_valid(form)
```

More reference at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#models-and-request-user

Comment: Hey Rohan, worked like a charm. Thank you so much, appreciate it greatly!